# jqueryui slider + jplayer volume value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jplayer, jquery-ui-slider

Actively listen and Combining the `jqueryui-slider` with the `jplayer voulme` in a value varible? Also display the volume value in a another div?
is there a way to grab the value of the `jqueryui slider` val and apply it to the `jplayer` vaolume's value?
html markup:

```
<ul class="toolbar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                <li><button class="jp-play" href="#">Play</button></li>
                <li><button class="jp-pause" href="#">Pause</button></li>
                <li><button class="jp-stop" href="#">Stop</button></li>
                <li><button class="jp-mute" href="#">Mute</button></li>
                <li><button class="jp-unmute" href="#">Unmute</button></li>
                <li><div class="jp-volume-bar"></div></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>


            </ul>
```

jquery:

```
my_jPlayer.jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $("#jp_container .track-default").click();
        },
        timeupdate: function(event) {
            my_extraPlayInfo.text(parseInt(event.jPlayer.status.currentPercentAbsolute, 10) + "%");
        },
        play: function(event) {
            my_playState.text(opt_text_playing);
        },
        pause: function(event) {
            my_playState.text(opt_text_selected);
        },
        ended: function(event) {
            my_playState.text(opt_text_selected);
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        volumeBarValue: volVal
    });
$(".jp-volume-bar").slider({
            value: 100,
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "min",
            animate: true
    });
    var volVal = $(".jp-volume-bar").slider("value");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be achievable using eventing. Look into jQuery event binding and event triggering if you are new to this concept.

Once you know how to do eventing, look at the jQuery slider's slide event. 
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider#event-slide.

You just have to update the jPlayer's volume and change the value inside the div that you want the volume

Comment: this will give me a whole number i need a float min 0 to max 1... is there a way to get a float value ?

Answer (score 4):

This is really very easy with the latest jplayer (Version: 2.1.0):

```
$('#sliderVolume').slider({
    value : 50,
    max: 100,
    range: 'min',
    animate: true,
    orientation: "vertical",

    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var volume = ui.value / 100;
        $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("volume", volume);
    }
});
```